# "Geodesic Distance" in Riemannian geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $(M,g)$ be a connected Riemannian manifold.

I have been working through the problems my advisor gave, and it mentioned the concept called "geodesic distance." Although I plan to ask my advisor what it means, I tried to guess the meaning in the meantime. My guess is that for $p,q\in M$, the geodesic distance between $p$ and $q$ is

$d_g(p,q) = \inf\{\int_{0}^{1}|\gamma'(t)|dt|\gamma:[0,1]\to M,\gamma(0)=p,\gamma(1)=q \textrm{ is a geodesic}\}$

However, Riemannian geometry has the concept of so-called Riemannian distance, defined by

$d_r(p,q) = \inf\{\int_{0}^{1}|\gamma'(t)|dt|\gamma:[0,1]\to M,\gamma(0)=p,\gamma(1)=q \textrm{ is a piecewise } C^1 \textrm{ curve}\}$

My question is, **do these distances agree in general?**

I think if $M$ is complete, they should be equal using Hopf-Rinow. But I don't know about the general case. I feel like it does not agree, but I cannot come up with a counterexample.

Comment: An interesting question is what happens if we consider piece-wise geodesics instead of geodesics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $M$ is not complete, then there need not exist any geodesic between two points at all, so that $d_g(p,q)=\infty$.  For instance, if $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a point removed, there is no geodesic from $p$ to $q$ if the removed point is on the line segment between them.

I don't know of any situation where $d_g$ is of interest and it does not coincide with $d_r$; I would assume "geodesic distance" always refers to $d_r$ even if the name is a bit inappropriate if $M$ is incomplete.

Comment: @OP It's worth noting the riemannian distance function is smooth iff there is a unique geodesic between every two points iff geodesics are length minimizing, and when they don't agree it is clear we don't get smoothness. Thus smoothness of the distance functions is equivalent to then being the same. Since we usually want a smooth metric, it often makes sense to restrict ourself to the context where these are equal (though not always; in nonsmooth contexts you often see $d^2$ considered to add some smoothness, in particular along the diagonal)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen If you consider the Riemannian distance of $\mathbb R^n\setminus \{pt\}$, it will be $d(x, y) = |x-y|$. You don't need existence and uniqueness of geodesics to have smoothness of $d$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, my bad; I was assuming simple connectivity, which is a hypothesis in the notes I was referencing that I forgot to include. The things I listed are clearly not equivalent without it. My bad!

Answer (score 8):

In general $d_g$ does not even define a metric: for example, let $M = \mathbb S^2 \setminus \{(1,0,0)\}$ with the usual metric. Let
$$p_\pm = (\sqrt 2, \pm \sqrt 2, 0).$$
Then
$$d_g (p_+, p_-) =  \frac{3\pi}{2}.$$
(Note that the usual shortest geodesic on $\mathbb S^2$ connecting $p_\pm $ passes through $(1,0,0)$). Let $q = (\sqrt 2, 0, \sqrt 2)$. Then $d_g (q, p_\pm )< \pi/2$ and hence

$$ d_g(p_-, p_+) > d_g (p_-, q) + d_g(q, p_+)$$

and triangle inequality is not satisfied. Indeed I have never saw a text where $d_g$ is used as a definition for the Riemannian distance. It's always $d_r$.